# Youtube API Copyright Notices?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a recruiting application that allows applicants to upload interview videos to Youtube through the API.

My question is I don't control the content and every so often a applicant uploads a copyright video and gets taken down. I have no actual strikes. I am concerned though I could get some and lose access to all my videos. What advice do you have? Any time a copyright owner submits a notice, I never contest it and so far that has been ok?

Comment: Do you want legal advice or help with a programming problem?

Comment: So you are letting other people upload videos to your channel?

Comment: Youtube API support says they offer support on here if I use the tags, which is why I posted this question.

Comment: Yes, I let other people upload videos to my channel. I use my channel as a place to save all of these videos for my team to view.